# Scratched finishing on IKEA furniture: how to fix

Tags: furniture, finishing, damage

During assembly, we managed to damage some outer finish and expose the wood underneath:

[image]

Is this fixable (say by putting some white "coating" on it)? If so, could you please point me to a solution? I struggled to Google for a solution on my own because I lacked the appropriate vocabulary. Thank you.

p.s. If this post doesn't meet the community's standards, please let me know how to improve it.

Comment: I would assume it's some type of enamel, but which type, specifically, that IKEA uses (and what the equivalent is that's commercially available) is an excellent question. Product recommendation questions are apt to be closed as they "quickly become obsolete", but sadly, IKEA furniture doesn't seem to be going away any time soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Kampel SeamFil seems to be an appropriate product if this is a laminate finish.  I'm looking for some myself.
If it's a paint finish, a thick touchup paint might work. Small brush applied.